# WPF, EventAggregator instead timer for reading Cursor position

Tags: c#, wpf, eventaggregator, mouse-position

I have wrote a WPF application in which Singleton class reads cursor coordinates and Observer class, that uses it, to publish them in labels.

In Singleton class for reading coordinates now I'm using timer. I want to replace him by EventAggregator, which will be using MouseMoveEvent. I have read a lot of tutorials, but I don't understand how EventAggregator works and how fit it to my app. Could anyone explain it on my own example ? Here is the code:

Singleton:

```
public class MousePointProvider
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref System.Drawing.Point lpPoint);

    private List<IObserver> _observerList;
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;

    private static MousePointProvider _instance = null;
    public static MousePointProvider Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new MousePointProvider();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Point _currentMousePosition;
    public Point CurrentMousePosition
    {
        get { return _currentMousePosition; }
    }

    private MousePointProvider()
    {
        _observerList = new List<IObserver>();

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                MousePositionChanged();
            };

        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void RegisterObserver(IObserver observer)
    {
        if (!_observerList.Contains(observer))
        {
            _observerList.Add(observer);
        }
    }

    public void UnregisterObserver(IObserver observer)
    {
        _observerList.Remove(observer);
    }

    public void MousePositionChanged()
    {
        GetCursorPos(ref _currentMousePosition);

        for (int i = 0; i < _observerList.Count; i++)
        {
            _observerList[i].MouseChanged(_currentMousePosition.X, _currentMousePosition.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Observer:

```
public class Listener : Canvas, IObserver
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Label labelX = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();
    System.Windows.Controls.Label labelY = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();

    public Listener()
    {
        MousePointProvider.Instance.RegisterObserver(this);

        this.Children.Add(labelX);
        Canvas.SetLeft(labelX, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(labelX, 100);

        this.Children.Add(labelY);
        Canvas.SetLeft(labelY, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(labelY, 200);
    }

    public void MouseChanged(int x, int y)
    {
        labelX.Content = "X=" + x.ToString();
        labelY.Content = "Y=" + y.ToString();
    }
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider looking at the Prism WPF framework. There is a lot of stuff in there, but what you are interested in is a class called EventAggregator that does all of this for you.

The EventAggregator lets you "publish" events that other classes can "subscribe" to. But unlike a conventional .Net event, the subscriber doesn't directly wire up an event handler to the object that raises the event. The EventAggregator acts as a go-between, so neither a publisher or its subscriber(s) need to be aware of each other.

Publishing and subscribing are one-liners, but are strangely convoluted, so I wrap EventAggregator in a helper class to simplify things a little:-

```
public class EventAggregatorWrapper
{
    private EventAggregator _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();

    // Publish
    public void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent eventToPublish)
    {
        GetEvent<TEvent>().Publish(eventToPublish);
    }

    // Subscribe
    public SubscriptionToken Subscribe<TEvent>(
        Action<TEvent> action, 
        ThreadOption threadOption = ThreadOption.PublisherThread, 
        bool keepSubscriberReferenceAlive = false, 
        Predicate<TEvent> filter = null)
    {
        return GetEvent<TEvent>().Subscribe(action, threadOption, keepSubscriberReferenceAlive, filter);
    }

    // Unsubscribe
    public void Unsubscribe<TEvent>(SubscriptionToken token)
    {
        GetEvent<TEvent>().Unsubscribe(token);
    }

    // Helper method to get a CompositePresentationEvent to act upon.
    private CompositePresentationEvent<TEvent> GetEvent<TEvent>()
    {
        return _eventAggregator.GetEvent<CompositePresentationEvent<TEvent>>();
    }
}
```

Next, ou need to create a class that represents your event "message" (a bit like an EventArgs object), e.g.:

```
public class CursorMovedMessage
{
    public Point NewPosition { get; set; }
}
```

Then to publish an event:-

```
var msg = new CursorMovedMessage();
msg.NewPosition = new Point(mouse.X, mouse.Y);

_eventAggregatorWrapper.Publish(msg);
```

A "consumer" would subscribe to these messages like this:-

```
_eventAggregatorWrapper.Subscribe<CursorMovedMessage>(CursorMovedMessageHandler, ThreadOption.BackgroundThread);

private void CursomrMovedMessageHandler(CursorMovedMessage msg)
{
    // Do something with the message object here
}
```

A subscriber can specify which thread to run the delegate on (E.g. UI thread, b/g thread, etc).